# Find all functions $f$ so that $d(f(x))=x$ for every natural $x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Help me find all functions $f(x)$, $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, so that $d(f(x))=x$ for every natural number $x$ where $d(x)$ is number of divisors of $x$.
My works until now: Clearly $f(1)=1$. We also have $d(n)\leq2\sqrt{n}$ so $d(f(x))=x\leq2\sqrt{f(x)}$ so $\frac{x^2}{4}\leq f(x)$. Using Fermat's little theorem and a little work on the function i also achieved that for every odd prime number $p$, $p|f(p)-1$.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $f(2)$ can be any prime. $f(3)$ can be any prime square. $f(4) can be any prime cube or product of two distinct primes ...

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $f$ such as being multiplicative?  Even still it's hard to imagine a satisfying characterization of such an open-ended function.

Comment: Well no there is no other information of the function.

Comment: $f(x)=p^{x-1},$where $p$ can be any prime.For example,$f(x)=2^{x-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that we can factor any number $k$ as $p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} p_3^{n_3} \ldots$ where $p_1, p_2, p_3 \ldots$ and unique primes and ${n_1} ,{n_2} ,{n_3} \ldots \geq1$. Then the number of factors of $k$ is $(n_1+1)(n_2+1)(n_3+1)\ldots$

So in fact first we should determine the factors of $x$ which we can use to choose values of $n_i$ which we can then assign to any primes of our choosing to give a value which we can assign to $f(x)$

Comment: I used this fact but still got no where for finding the function itself.

Comment: to clarify are you looking for all possible functions or just an example of a function?

Comment: @CODE You should explain what your source is.  Your comments strongly suggest that the question is not internally motivated.

Comment: It was a question from one of our school Olympiad exams. They didn't give the answers even after the exam.

Comment: @john It says all possible functions.

Comment: @CODE that's what I originally thought but your comment suggests you want a particular function. The above is a method for finding every possible function that satisfies the condition. Note that there are infinitely many such functions.